# Updated MAMP on Windows 7 and started getting error when trying Laravel migrate - PDOException::("could not find driver")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Since MySQL was a bit outdated and didn't have the JSON data type for database fields, I decided to reinstall MAMP so I can get the latest version. Sadly after doing that I noticed my php artisan migrate command was not working and I keep getting an error.

I read that I have to uncomment `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in my php.ini file, but that line was not commented anyways.

The entire error is:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lol and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=lol", "root", "", [])
      C:\MAMP\htdocs\League Of Legends Backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your `phpinfo();`? It should improve insight of what's going on...

Comment: phpinfo(); gives quite a lot of information. I don't think I can even post the entire thing here. Anything specific that I should look for?

Comment: Hmm, the first section, `Core`, `pdo` / `pdo_mysql`, these are the ones i can think of